# How to Serve Dynamically Created URL Paths with Go?

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, go, react-router, browser-history

I am using react-router and [browserHistory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)'s pushState in a reactjs project. This project lets a user create a note which creates a new path. To serve this type of site I need to serve the same HTML file to every path besides the static content. So my nodejs code looks like this.

```
// Serve the static content
app.use('/static/css/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../react-ui/build/static/css')));
app.use('/static/js/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../react-ui/build/static/js')));
app.use('/static/media/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../react-ui/build/static/media')));
app.use('/static/img/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../react-ui/build/static/img')));
app.use('/img/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../react-ui/build/img')));

// Serve the same HTML file to everything else
app.use('*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../react-ui/build')));
```

I don't see any wildcard support for the Go FileServer. Currently I have all the static pages served using Go code similar to this.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func init(){
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("web"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    http.Handle("/static-page-1/", http.StripPrefix("/static-page-1/", fs))
    http.Handle("/static-page-2/", http.StripPrefix("/static-page-2/", fs))
    http.Handle("/static-page-3/", http.StripPrefix("/static-page-3/", fs))
}
```

Is it possible to serve content to dynamically generated URL paths with a Go server?

If the Handle method supported variables then I'd write the code like this

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("web"))
http.Handle("/static/", fs)
http.Handle("/{unknownUserPath}", http.StripPrefix("/{unknownUserPath}", fs))
```

{unknownUserPath} would be any path that a user types in that is not under /static/ path.

Here's the go project structure

[image]

Here's the server based on @putu answer

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func adaptFileServer(fs http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        staticIndex := strings.Index(req.URL.Path, "/static/");
        imgIndex := strings.Index(req.URL.Path, "/img/");

        if staticIndex == -1 && imgIndex == -1 {
            fsHandler := http.StripPrefix(req.URL.Path, fs)
            fsHandler.ServeHTTP(w, req)
        } else {
            fs.ServeHTTP(w, req)
        }
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func init() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("web"))
    http.Handle("/", adaptFileServer(fs))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to serve static contents with URL pattern `/*` to a specific directory, then use the answer provided by jeevatkm.

If you need slightly customizable version, you need a kind of *adapter* that map the URL path to static file handler (`http.FileServer`). The example code looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
)

func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello world!"))
}

func adaptFileServer(fs http.Handler, mux http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        //Use your Path matcher here.
        //For demonstration, REGEX match is used
        //and it's probably not the most efficient.
        staticRegex := regexp.MustCompile("^/static-page-[0-9]+/")
        if matches := staticRegex.FindStringSubmatch(req.URL.Path); matches != nil {
            log.Printf("Match: %v, %v", req.URL.Path, matches[0])
            fsHandler := http.StripPrefix(matches[0], fs)
            fsHandler.ServeHTTP(w, req)
        } else if mux != nil {
            log.Printf("Doesn't match, pass to other MUX: %v", req.URL.Path)
            mux.ServeHTTP(w, req)
        } else {
            http.Error(w, "Page Not Found", http.StatusNotFound)
        }
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func init() {
    //Usual routing definition with MUX
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/hello", helloHandler)

    //"Dynamic" static file server.
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("web"))
    http.Handle("/", adaptFileServer(fs, mux))
}

func main() {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

In the above adapter example, if request path match to a specific *pattern* (`/static-page-*/` in the above example), it will be passed to `http.FileServer`. If doesn't match, and if a multiplexer is specified, it will call `mux.ServeHTTP`. Otherwise it will return `404` error.

If you want another matching rule, just change the `regex` pattern (or use your custom matcher).

**Note:**
Please don't use a same handler instance for `FileServer` and `mux`. For example, when you call `http.Handle`, it use `http.DefaultServeMux` to handle routing. If you pass `http.DefaultServeMux` as the second argument of `adaptFileServer` you may end up with endless recursion.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the file server to work without the mux server object, but if I ever want to add any services then I'll need to use it. I added the code I'm using to my question

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the [`gorilla/mux` package](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) is great for dynamic routing support. But it still doesn't let you strip prefixes from dynamic routes. Here's how you can get that to work:

```
fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
r.PathPrefix("/user/{name}/").HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Figure out what the resolved prefix was.
    name := mux.Vars(r)["name"]
    prefix := fmt.Sprintf("/user/%s/", name)
    // Strip it the normal way.
    http.StripPrefix(prefix, fileServer).ServeHTTP(w, r)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to server dynamic link in golang file server is as follow

first of all you have to implement a middle ware to recognize the dynamic link, or query link, for example, we generate a file with dynamic link `/some-hex-decimal` which leads to file

and also you have a shortner which is a map from this `hex-decimal` to actual path

code is as follow

```
func (us *urlSplitter) splitUrl(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //============== Read requested query string
    exn := r.URL.Query().Get("dynamic-link")
    if exn == "" {
        responseJsonStatus(w, "access-file",
            "query string 'exn' not found",
            "", http.StatusBadRequest, nil)
        return
    }

    //============== Remove query string
    r.URL.Query().Del("exn")

    //============== Generate file access path
    supplier := func() (filter interface{}) {
        return bson.D{
            {"exn", exn},
        }
    }
    ifu := us.repo.FindExportationWithFilter(r.Context(), supplier).Get()

    if ifu.Data() == nil {
        responseJsonStatus(w, "access-file",
            "request file not found",
            "", http.StatusNotFound, nil)
        return
    }

    foundEx := ifu.Data().(*entitie) // stored data in cache or any other where

    if foundEx.ExportationStatus.StatusName == utils.InTemporaryRepo ||
        foundEx.ExportationStatus.StatusName == utils.FileManagementFailed {
        responseJsonStatus(w, "access-file",
            "file is not server-able",
            "", http.StatusBadRequest, nil)
    }

    //============== Call next handler to take care of request
    r2 := new(http.Request)
    *r2 = *r
    r2.URL = new(url.URL)
    *r2.URL = *r.URL
    r2.URL.Path = foundEx.ServeUrl

    next.ServeHTTP(w, r2)
})
}
```

now for using this middle ware we have to chain it up on http.server as follow

```
func (s *Server) Start() {
    add := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", s.host, s.port)

    log.GLog.Logger.Info("Starting HttpFileHandler", "fn", "httpFileServer.Start",
        "address", add, "servePath", s.servePath)

    //============== Initial Middleware
    sp := newSplitter(s.repo)
    au := newAuth(s.usCli)

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(s.servePath))

    http.Handle("/", sp.splitUrl(fs)))

    err := http.ListenAndServe(add, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.GLog.Logger.Error("Error on starting file http server",
            "fn", "httpFileServer.init",
            "err", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

you now can change dynamic link middle ware to handle you dynamics in any shape which is to lead fileserver to correct file path.

Answer (score -2):

`http.FileServer` is good choice for serving static files from directory and it's subdirectories.

```
func main() {
  http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))

  log.Println("Listening...")
  if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

It will serve any files under `/static/*` directory and its subdirectories via `http://localhost:8080/static/<path-to-file>`.

So design your directory structure and map it via one or more file server handler.

---

**EDIT:**

As asked in the comment. Serve static files form root and underneath.

```
http.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("web"))))
```

It means files under `web/*` will be served from root `/`.

Comment: That part is working, but what I'm trying to do is something like this, `http.Handle("/*", http.StripPrefix("/*", fs))` where the * would be a wildcard.

Comment: Okay I understand. Just to clarify do you mean root `/` and underneath is for serving static files?

Comment: Additions to the answer, please have a look.

Comment: This is how my Go server is currently setup. Checkout my second example in the question

Comment: I added another example to clarify the issue